# Use of Attributes... INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

This is just something I was thinking as I was learning on Attributes and I was using the INotifyPropertyChanged too much, is just and Idea and I would like to hear some opinios about it.( I know this would require some work on the compiler and not on the cosumer side)

Since INotifyPropertyChanged is used with the same Pattern most of the time ..  just like calling the method that fire ups the event with the name of the property ,could it be designed as and Attribute and using Auto-Properties? So that the compiler knows it need to add the call to the PropertyChanged event? 
So if we have the class....

```
public class DemoCustomer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

  private string companyNameValue = String.Empty;
         ...
}
```

Instead of declaring the property

```
public string CompanyName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.companyNameValue;
        }

        set
        {
                       if (value != this.companyNameValue)
                       {
                          this.companyNameValue = value;
                          NotifyPropertyChanged("CompanyName");
                       }
        }
    }
```

we could do something like this if we can indicate to the compiler by this attribute that it needs to generate a call to the PropertyChanged with the name of the property if the new value is different from the previous

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public string CompanyName
{
  get;set;
}
```

We could still keep coding in the old way for some custom behaviours when no using the Attribute..

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone happens across this thread and is using C# 5 (VS 2012+, .NET 4.5+).  This case be done "more easily" now with `CallerMemberNameAttribute`.  This attribute is applied to a string parameter and causes the compiler to pass in the name of the calling method/property when the default value us used (i.e. when and argument is not passed).  Making implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` less tiresome.  For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string myProperty;

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return myProperty; }
        set
        {
            myProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

So, you just need `OnPropertyChanged()` in each setter to send out the event and don't have to deal with a hard-coded string for the property name.

Comment: Still not as elegant as simple attribute. Which is what it should be.

Comment: This is once and done, could even be a base class for other classes. Is adding an attribute to each property is more elegant?

Comment: Sure, just can't use default prop definition with it.

Comment: okay, yeah.  If it were base close you _could_ use the default attribute.  But I think what is the default is largely implementation-specific.  You can still put the default attribute on the property in the implementing class..  The property-changed handler doesn't need to change to support that...

Answer (score 7):

This style of thinking is called Aspect Oriented Programming (or AOP).  You can achieve the end result by adding a post build action using Mono's Cecil to go through properties with that attribute and modify the behavior of the property and spit out the newly compiled assembly with the appropriate behavior.  You can look at [Jason Bock](http://www.jasonbock.net/JB/Default.aspx)'s [Dimecast](http://dimecasts.net) on "[Leveraging Cecil to inject code into your Assemblies](http://dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/59)"

Comment: Very good reading.. Thanks a lot... I started to use postsharp... that's why I'm pointing the other answer. But this is usefull as well.