# How do I correctly implement INotifyPropertyChanged for my bool property and bind to CheckBox.IsChecked?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Novice here. I've been trying to wrap my head around databinding, and wanted to do try out two-way binding of a checkbox in the view to a boolean in a separate class that I've called "State". The point is to ensure that they are always in sync.

So I've made a checkbox in the view and bound it to the aforementioned boolean property in the State-class, accompanied by a button that bypasses the checkbox and toggles the boolean property directly (aptly labeled 'Ninja!'). The point was to test that the checkbox' databinding reacts when the property changes. However, I can't for the best of me figure out how the OnPropertyChanged-method is supposed to be invoked when the property changes.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="232,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Ninja!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="228,182,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
```

And the code for the "State"-class I've made:

```
namespace TestTwoWayBinding
{
    class State : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private bool _checked;
        public bool Checked {
            get
            {
                return _checked;
            }
            set
            {
                _checked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(Checked);
            }
        }       

        public void Toggle()
        {
            if (!Checked)
            {
                Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {  
                Checked = false;

            }
        }

        public State(bool c)
        {
            this.Checked = c;
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Checked));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the code-behind on the view for initialization and handling the events:

```
namespace TestTwoWayBinding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private State _state;
        public MainWindow()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();
            _state = new State((bool)checkBox.IsChecked);
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _state.Toggle();
        }
    }
}
```

From what I gather, OnPropertyChanged expects a String propertyName, but I don't know what that would entail here. When I put in the name of the property (Checked), then that naturally refers to a boolean, not a string. What am I not getting? And what else am I doing wrong, as the checkbox doesn't register the property change when I change it through the button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two answers which suggest you pass the string literal `"Checked"` will work, but IMHO aren't the best way to do it. Instead, I prefer using `[CallerMemberName]` when implementing the `OnPropertyChanged()` method. (I have no idea what that third answer is all about…it doesn't appear to have anything to do with this question, and I'd guess it was just copy/pasted from somewhere else).

Here's an example of how I'd write your `State` class:

```
class State : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private bool _checked;
    public bool Checked
    {
        get { return _checked; }
        set { _checked = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }       

    public void Toggle()
    {
        Checked = !Checked;
    }

    public State(bool c)
    {
        this.Checked = c;
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The key here is that the parameter marked with `[CallerMemberName]` will automatically be filled in with the correct value from the caller, simply by not passing any value. The default value of `null` is there just so the compiler will allow the caller to not pass a value.

Note that I also simplified the `Toggle()` method. There's no need to use an `if` statement to transform one `bool` value into another; that's what the Boolean operators are there for.

I also changed the `OnPropertyChanged()` method so that it's thread-safe, i.e. won't crash if some code unsubscribes the last handler from the `PropertyChanged` event between the time the event field is compared to `null` and the time the event is actually raised. Typically, this is a non-issue as these properties are nearly always accessed only from a single thread, but it's easy enough to protect against and is a good habit to get into.

Note that in C# 6, you have the option of just writing `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));` for the method body. Not everyone is using the new compiler 100% of the time yet, so I just mention that as an optional choice for you.

Naturally, you also need to set the `DataContext` correctly, as shown in [one of the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36971642):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _state = new State((bool)checkBox.IsChecked);
    this.DataContext = _state;
}
```

Though, personally, I'm not sure I'd bother with the constructor. You appear to have no other code that would set `checkBox.IsChecked`, so it seems to me that you're always going to get the default value anyway. Besides, you can't create your view model class in XAML if it doesn't have a parameterized constructor; in the future, you may prefer to configure your `DataContext` like that. E.g.:

```
<Window.DataContext>
  <l:State Checked="True"/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

And in the window's constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _state = (State)this.DataContext;
}
```

See also the related Q&A [Automatically INotifyPropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/527602). The question there is really about something different — they want to implement the interface without having to explicitly write anything in the property setter — but for better or worse, the answers they got are really more about your scenario, where it's just a question of *simplifying* the property setter implementation rather than making it completely automatic.

I have to admit, I would've thought there would have been another question already with which to mark yours as a duplicate. And I did find lots of *related* questions. But nothing that focuses directly on just "how do I implement and use a view model that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`?", which is really what your question seems to be about.

**Addendum**:

I did some more searching, and while none of these seem like they would be considered exact duplicates per se, they all have good information that help address the question about implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

[Use of Attributes… INotifyPropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1662745)
[INotifyPropertyChanged for model and viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23359154)
[BindableBase vs INotifyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28844518)
[How to write “ViewModelBase” in MVVM (WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36149863)

Comment: The `OnPropertyChanged` method can now be shortened in C#6 to a single line of code using the null-conditional operator: `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`

Answer (score 3):

You are real close.  You need to make 2 small changes and your test works:

1. Assign the `DataContext` of your Window to the _state variable.
2. Put the string "Checked" into the `OnPropertyChanged` and pass `propertyName` to the `PropertyChangedEventArgs` in the `OnPropertyChanged` method.

So your MainWindow ctor becomes:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _state = new State((bool)checkBox.IsChecked);
        this.DataContext = _state;
    }
```

and the State class file looks like:

```
class State : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private bool _checked;
    public bool Checked
    {
        get
        {
            return _checked;
        }
        set
        {
            _checked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Checked");
        }
    }

    public void Toggle()
    {
        if (!Checked)
        {
            Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Checked = false;

        }
    }

    public State(bool c)
    {
        this.Checked = c;
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

As a novice, I recommend you learn more about Model-View-ViewModel [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) Design Pattern.  It is a common pattern with WPF and helps encourage separation of concerns (keeping your business logic out of your user interface logic)

Answer (score 0):

The `OnPropertyChanged` method expects the  `Checked` property's name as argument - at the moment, you're passing its value!

This means, change the `Checked` property declaration to:

```
public bool Checked {
    get
    {
        return _checked;
    }
    set
    {
        _checked = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Checked");
    }
 }
```