# WPF listbox binding , auto select selected item from viw Model

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, viewmodel

I have a listbox and a modelview , which I used to bind listbox items from a obervable collection.

My requirement is that I need to set the selectedItem as well as selectedIndex from view model, so the selected item can be visible to the user.

Hope somebody have solution for me

Answer (score 0):

Make a SelectedItem property in your view model after that you can write something like this

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

in your XAML.

Comment: I want to  this code make   `var charles = new Person() { FirstName = "Charles", LastName = "Darwin" };
            viewModel.SelectedPerson = charles;`  changes to the list

Comment: and this is the seletectedPerson property from my view class  `public Person SelectedPerson
        {
            get { return m_SelectedPerson; }
            set => SetProperty(ref m_SelectedPerson, value);
        }`

Comment: in my xaml   I have `<StackPanel Margin="0,0,-0.4,113">
            <ListBox  Name="personsListBox"
 SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedPerson.Index }"
ItemsSource="{Binding  Persons}"                     
                      
DisplayMemberPath="LastName"

SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            
            <Label Content="Selected person"/>
            
            <Label Content="{Binding SelectedPerson.FirstName}"/>
          
            <Label Content="{Binding SelectedPerson.LastName}"/>            
        </StackPanel>`

Comment: If you want to change it after your viewmodel loaded to your window you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged to your view model.

Comment: the selected item already working , I want it reflected on the list [ get selected - in UI]

Comment: I do implement this  `public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
            {
                field = newValue;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }`

Comment: [INotify Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970912/how-do-i-correctly-implement-inotifypropertychanged-for-my-bool-property-and-bin) Can you look at this, I didn't see any mistake in your code but try to debug it, maybe the program isn't invoking the event.

Comment: actually this code working    `var pi=viewModel.Persons.Where((p, b) => p.FirstName.Equals(charles.FirstName)); 
            var p1 = (Person) pi.SingleOrDefault();
            viewModel.SelectedPerson = p1;`

Comment: but it is not the purpose